# Rails: Filling in a dynamic field using capybara

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, capybara

I have a text field that is dynamically created via javascript with the long id:

`user_user_skills_attributes_69878013874980_skill_title`

where the `69878013874980` is a generated timestamp.

How do I fill in the field with this id in a capybara test?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `set` command. Something like:

```
find(:css, "input[id^='user_user_skills_attributes_'][id$='_skill_title']").set("This is a test title")
```

Comment: I know this is an old post, but if you remember, what is this called? I.e. how would I google `id$=` to set these random id's for capybara. Thanks in advance. @mccannf