# Locating element with dynamic ID's in Cucumber Ruby with Capybara

Tags: ruby, capybara

I have a form that allows a user to add elements where the id is then generated dynamically.

The first text input id appears simply as

```
id=car[car_attributes][0][name]
```

Which enables me to simply

```
fill_in "car_0_name", with: "Ford"
```

When the user adds another input to the page the locator is shown as

```
id=car[car_attributes][1664259795784][name]
```

The id generated for the additional inputs never appears to be the same.

How can I ensure that my tests target the correct element dynamincally when adding additinal inputs?

If possible I'd like to collect the elements and store the in an array and reference the element like

```
cars = page.all()
```

and then access the one I want:

```
fill_in cars[1], with: "Nissan"
```

Comment: Show the full HTML of the inputs along with any associated label elements please

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you solved this, but this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336682/rails-filling-in-a-dynamic-field-using-capybara) might be what you are looking for.

So your question's example would be, assuming this is the id:

```
find(:css, "input[id^='car_attributes_'][id$='name']").set("Nissan")
```